# Postman- Pass dynamic parameters to collection at run-time which is not part of response

Tags: postman, web-api-testing, postman-collection-runner, postman-pre-request-script

I have created postman collection for unit testing of APIs.
I need to handle below scenario.

My second API generates OTP and sends it over email but its not part of response.
I want to pass that OTP in request body of 3rd API.

I am executing postman collection using Collection Runner.
Is there any way I can pause the execution and set this environment variable and then resume.
Or any other better option. Please suggest.

Comment: I recommend to use an email provider that provides an API (eg GMail does https://developers.google.com/gmail/api). Then you could read the email containing the OTP with an additional request from Postman, save it as environment variable and use it in the next request.

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to do it but it require some knowledge of server side technologies ( for example **Spring boot**). you can create a new api which is kind of wrapper over your OTP api and it will read the OTP from either your **mail/DB** and send it as a part of Http response  and then you can use that wrapper API in your Postman collection to fetch the OTP and then save it as a **env variable** and use it in further apis. I am also doing the same way.